# protobuf::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited(): Assertion `empty_string_ != __null' failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe

I tried to convert the VGG16 weights pretrained by [Places365 dataset](https://github.com/metalbubble/places365) from caffe to tensorflow using [caffe to tensorflow](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow). But I got the following errors:

```
kang@herakles:~/Documents/work_code_PC1/caffe-tensorflow$ python convert.py deploy_vgg16_places365.prototxt --caffemodel vgg16_places365.caffemodel --data-output-path placesnet.npy --code-output-path placesnet.py
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
python: ./google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h:80: const string& google::protobuf::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited(): Assertion `empty_string_ != __null' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How to fix that error? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: did you find an answer to this problem? I have had it myself

Comment: This problem happened in my work computer Ubuntu 15.10. And I tried to use my own computer with Ubuntu 16.04. It worked. So I did not go deep into this error. Sorry. But if you figure it out, you can post here. Thank you very much.

Comment: My problem was solved when I discovered that one of my dependent libraries was linking to the static library (libprotobuf.a) while the rest of my application was dynamically linking to libprotobuf.so. Removing the static linkage fixed it for me

Comment: How to check which dependent libraries linked to libprotobuf.a and the rest application linked to which library? I am new with Ubuntu. Thank you very much.

Comment: it depends on how you build your application - I was using CMake, so found one of the CMakelist.txt files had instructions to link against the .a file, whereas none of the other CMakelist.txt files had such a reference